Marginal distribution is normal, but the joint distribution is not. Why?

Denote the CDF of standard normal distribution as $\phi(\cdot)$. The
joint CDF of $(X,Y)$ is
$   F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \phi(x)\phi(y)[1-\alpha(1-\phi(x))(1-\phi(y))]$ where $\alpha \in (-1,0)\cup(0,1)$. Prove that the marginal distribution of $X$
and $Y$ is standard normal but the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is not bivariate normal.

It is obvious that the marginal distribution is normal since
$$
F_X(x) = \lim_{y\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lim_{y\to\infty}\phi(x)\phi(y)[1-\alpha(1-\phi(x))(1-\phi(y))] = \phi(x)
$$
and so is $F_Y(y)$.
But I cannot find an elegent approach to show that $(X,Y)$ is not bivariate normal. How to do that?

But for $\alpha=0$ it is, right?

Thank you. I have edited my question.

Naively I would look at the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Y\leq0.$ I think it should be possible to show by explicit calculation that the mean is different from the median if $\alpha\neq0.$
